# How to take solr index collection backup?

Tags: hadoop, solr

How to take Solr collection back into lfs or hdfs?

While I am running this query: curl '[quickstart.cloudera:8983/solr/admin/…](http://www.quickstart.cloudera:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=snapshot&collection=testhtml&location=/user/cloudera/)'; I got error:

```
ml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <response> <lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unknown action: BACKUP</str><int name="code">400</int></lst> </response>
```

Comment: The collection backup API was added in Solr 6.1, so it depends on which version of Solr you're using (and which Cloudera version you're using). Otherwise you'll have to use the replication endpoints for each node yourself (or use one of the utilities written to do it for you)

Comment: Thanks for your reply MastsLindh. 
we are using cdh5.5 nd solr-4.10.3

Comment: Hello MatsLindh, 
can we do the sorting on date in solr not in query?

Comment: Create a new question with the appropriate details instead of using a comment.. I'm not also sure what you mean, so be sure to expand on the issue in the question.